# A way to poll users desktop for Unhandled Exception popup

Tags: c#, windows-services, screenshot, polling

A bit of background: I have an application that is used by multiple people and I rely on them to report errors to me so that I may improve the application. The problem is some of the errors are unhandled and they completely break the application (an **information box** is used to display this exception). I suspect these errors occur often but aren't reported to me. My idea for a solution is to install another application (whatever form it may be in) on their desktops that constantly polls the PC's screen and takes a snapshot. At this point I would identify if the  **information box** is found within the snapshot and then send it to myself, otherwise i dispose of the snapshot.

The furthest I got was to create a windows service to take a print screen, but it took a snapshot of session 0 and not session 1 (I also couldn't figure out how to take a snapshot of session 1). That being said I also had to tick the "Allow service to interact with desktop" checkbox for the service which I am told is bad practice. Am i going in the right direction to create a windows service or is there another way I haven't thought of?

Any help would be appreciated, thank you

Comment: The "best practice" would be to fix the original application so there aren't any unhandled exceptions. If you want to go to the safest extreme, you could build in error reporting and high level exception handling to trap any exceptions that are currently thrown from unknown locations.  
Installing custom software to monitor custom software is not the answer...

Comment: Agree with @William_Wilson.  At one company I worked for, we built a try/catch around the main execution method that would catch any exception not caught by a specific error handler and log/report it.

Answer (score 1):

I would have logging inside of the application - if you encounter the unhandled exception you can save all of the relevant data (stacktrace, exception, state of variables) and send it in an report email to yourself (if the pc running the app is not connected to the internet, just save the report to some local folder and later you can retrive it manually).

You can even show input dialog box, where the user can enter some information about actions he was doing, before the error ocured.

Comment: Look up AppDomain.UnhandledException, and search for unhandled exceptions on Stack Overflow.  Handling unhandled exceptions the way @videokojot suggests is the standard way to do this